# Having a hard time trying to filter out the hits in my Algolia InstantSearch searchController

Tags: swift, full-text-search, algolia, instantsearch

My goal is to filter out hits by schoolID. School users on my app have unique schoolIDs and I want them to be able to search through events that only they created and not see any other school's events. I’ve been wanting to figure this out ever since I got the Algolia implemented into my app and I just can’t wrap my head around it, the concept seems so easy to explain but when i try to implement it, there is literally no change in my search results.

I copied the code that one of the Algolia team members in the community forum replied with, but it still doesn’t filter out the hits by schoolID, I will attach my block of code in the updateSearchResults() method, **please** point out **any** mistakes you see in my code, I’ve been gunning to fix this big issue in my app for a while. Thanks in advance.

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
let settings = Settings()

    .set(\.searchableAttributes, to: [.default("eventName")])
    .set(\.attributesForFaceting, to: [.filterOnly("schoolID")])
    .set(\.attributesToRetrieve, to: ["*"])

 searchResultsIndex.setSettings(settings) { (result) in
    if case .success(let response) = result {
        print("Response: \(response.wrapped)")
    }
}
getTheSchoolsID { (schoolID) in
    if let id = schoolID {
        let schoolID: String = id
    }
    
    let query = Query(searchBar.searchTextField.text!).set(\.filters, to: "schoolID:\(schoolID)")

    searchResultsIndex.search(query: query) { (result) in
        if case .success(let response) = result {
            print("Query Success!")
        }
    }
}
```

}